# How to add validator tag to a nested field

Tags: go, validation

Here is my code

```
type AbstractAccount struct {
    Email        string `gorm:"unique;type:varchar"`
    PasswordHash string `gorm:"unique;type:varchar"`
}

type Planner struct {
    AbstractAccount
}
```

I want to add a custom validator tag to `Email` through `Planner` for example

```
type Planner struct {
    AbstractAccount `validator:"Email:customTag"`
}
```

Is there a way to to it in go validator, or is there any library to do it?

Comment: did you tried it with [validator](https://github.com/go-playground/validator).. [struct-level-validation](https://github.com/go-playground/validator/blob/ce28d7c4b27fbcafff82bc87a8bf58257beb9030/_examples/struct-level/main.go)

Comment: Do you want to validate `Email` when `AbstractAccount` has defined a custom tag `Email:customTag`, if not, don't validate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Sample program](https://go.dev/play/p/NJpUzwXy6ti)
inside that sample program there is a function called getFieldsWithCustomTag  it takes a reflect value as an argument and recursively searches for fields with the tag c-tag:true(you can change this). It appends these fields to a slice and, if a nested struct is encountered, recursively calls itself to search for fields in the nested struct.